# Navigate from app.js, that is outside of the BrowserRouter wrapping

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";
import { startSetExpenses } from "./actions/expenses";
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import './styles/styles.scss';
import AppRouter from "./routers/AppRouter";
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

const navigate = useNavigate();

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
);

const loadingComponent = <div><p>Loading...</p></div>;

root.render(loadingComponent);

store.dispatch(startSetExpenses())
.then(() => {
    root.render(jsx);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching expenses:", error);
});

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if(user){
        console.log("LoggedIN");
        navigate("/dashboard");
    }else{
        console.log("LoggedOUT");
        navigate("/");
    }
})
```

AppRouter.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import EditExpense from '../components/EditExpense';
import AddExpense from '../components/AddExpense';
import ExpenseDashboardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashboard';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';
import { Routes, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter >
            <Header/>
            <Routes >
                <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
                <Route path="/dashboard" element={<ExpenseDashboardPage />} />
                <Route path="/create" element={<AddExpense />} />
                <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditExpense />} />
                <Route path="/help" element={<HelpPage />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> 
            </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

The `store.dispatch(startSetExpenses())` is to fetch the initial data from firebase. Till it gets resolved, I am rendering the loadingComponent on screen.
What I expected by using the useNavigate from react-router-dom was to navigate to the "/" path when user is not logged in, in the onAuthStateChanged, and to "/dashboard" when a user is logged in.
But it isn't working. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call React hooks outside React components or custom React hooks. I suggest moving the `useNavigate` hook call and auth state change listener into `AppRouter` and hoisting the `BrowserRouter` to the index file to wrap `AppRouter` to provide it the routing context.

Example:

App:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';
import configureStore from "./store/configureStore";
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import { startSetExpenses } from "./actions/expenses";
import './styles/styles.scss';
import AppRouter from "./routers/AppRouter";
import { auth } from './firebase/firebase';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("app"));

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

const loadingComponent = <div><p>Loading...</p></div>;

root.render(loadingComponent);

store.dispatch(startSetExpenses())
  .then(() => {
    root.render(jsx);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching expenses:", error);
  });
```

AppRouter:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import LoginPage from '../components/LoginPage';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import NotFound from '../components/NotFound';
import EditExpense from '../components/EditExpense';
import AddExpense from '../components/AddExpense';
import ExpenseDashboardPage from '../components/ExpenseDashboard';
import HelpPage from '../components/HelpPage';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("LoggedIN");
        navigate("/dashboard");
      } else {
        console.log("LoggedOUT");
        navigate("/");
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<ExpenseDashboardPage />} />
        <Route path="/create" element={<AddExpense />} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" element={<EditExpense />} />
        <Route path="/help" element={<HelpPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should debug. Is `onAuthStateChanged` ever called? Maybe it's not running?

`useNavigate` is a hook, it must be used inside a component.

Comment: Yes the onAuthStateChanged is getting called